# Magento 2 : How do i ONLY display the number currently in cart?

Tags: magento2, php, mini-cart, items

I am trying to display the number of items currently in my cart, however not getting any result. In magento 1 we just just add the following to our phtml file and it will just echo the no. of items in cart.

```
Mage::getModel(‘checkout/cart’)->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
```

This of course does not work in in magento 2 (version 2.0.2). Within my custom html file. I just need to  **echo** just the number, just like you get when get a number on the mini cart.
This is the section of code i need to put it in

```
<span class="cart-text"><strong>Basket:</strong>
    <span class="cart-count">??????</span> item(s)
</span>
```

I need to put the number in replace of the question marks.
This may be a simple question, however i am still in the early stages of my learning curve, help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
 echo $helper->getItemsCount();
```

Comment: That works exactly as i needed it. Thank you @Qaisar Satti

Comment: It's not working if caches are enabled.